# Run mplayer playlist from a python script

Tags: python, playlist, mplayer

first of all, Thank you for all the help I've gotten from this place so far! Keep up the good work!

This is my first programming project so forgive me if this is a stupid question but I've come to a complete stop and can't find the answer anywhere!

I've created a playlist and I can run it from the terminal with mplayer. But I want to make a Python script that does it for me including shuffling the list.

I've managed to find a script that play a single song but not from a playlist.

```
import commands
import os

SOUND = 'music.mp3'

command = 'mplayer %s 1>/dev/null 2>&1' % SOUND
os.system(command)
```

Ohyeah, I should probably mention that this is on a Debian system if that makes any difference.

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you post your best attempt so far? Then it's easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This works..

```
import subprocess
myplaylist = "/path/to/playlist/somePlaylist.txt"
subprocess.call(['mplayer', '-vo', 'null', '-ao', 'alsa', '-playlist', myplaylist, '-shuffle'])
```

Actually, after trying, your way is heaps better because I can use it to log mplayers output.

I create a pipe

```
pi@raspberrypi$ mkfifo /tmp/pipe
```

then use the following command in my python script

```
command = "mplayer -vo null -ao alsa -playlist /home/pi/music/HelensFaves.txt -slave -input file=/tmp/pipe -quiet -loop 0 > /tmp/mlog.txt"
os.system(command)
```

and then control mplayer by sending commands to the pipe

```
echo "pt_step 1" > /tmp/pipe
```